# What is preventing some pages in my wordpress pages from showing any content?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I changed the database prefix in my Wordpress database tables and ever since some pages do not display any content. I have renamed the tables back to its original names and the pages are still not showing.

Comment: does it match $table_prefix in wp-config.php?

Comment: Of course you took a backup of your database and site, BEFORE doing this serious change to your database. RIGHT? So all you need to do is restore the backup and then have another go at your changes

Comment: some other things to check or change. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/

Comment: @inarilo the tutorial u referred was what l followed in the first place..

Comment: @RiggsFolly l backed up with updraftplus. but l am skeptical about it because when l try to import the database into xampp to view the tables...only 8 tables are imported and my xampp gives the an error of error time exceeded..

Comment: phpMyAdmin is effected by the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`. Either increase that, or run the import from mysql on the command line

Comment: @RiggsFolly l have increased the max_execution_time in php.ini  to 1500 seconds in xampp but l keep getting this error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\UtfString.php on line 118...Pleaseany suggestions

Comment: Not used XAMPP in a while. But maybe in the Alias config for phpMyAdmin there is a command like `php_admin_value max_execution_time 300` and if that is the case, it is that limit you need to increase. Then put the `php.ini` value back to something sensible

Comment: But it would be simpler to use the `mysql.exe` processor from the command line as that has no limitations `mysql -u root -p` and then use `source path/to/backup.sql`

Comment: @RiggsFolly...l have successfully imported the database but as l try to login to the worpress this is the reply l get     ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums.

Comment: @RiggsFolly..thanks a bunch. l have fixed the issue. l really appreciate your kindness